# php minify - rewritten URL cache by browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, minify

I am trying to create rewritten URL for CSS/JS with php minify. At tools.pingdom I recieved this message:
The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:

http://www.xxx.xx/assets/minify/css-combined.css
http://www.xxx.xx/assets/minify/js-combined.js

At the root I have .htaccess containing expires and header rules:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
ExpiresDefault      "access plus 1 month"
# cache.appcache needs re-requests 
# in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
# Your document html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# RSS feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz|woff)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

in the folder of minify there is following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^(.*).js$ index.php?g=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ index.php?g=$1
```

Could you please help me? What am i doing wrong?

Thank you=)

Best regards,
Russianroot

Comment: I think you'll have to add headers in your minify/index.php file. See [this post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/intelligent-php-cache-control/) on how to do that. The reason is, even though the browser requested a .css or .js file, since the request was rewritten and (assuming you didn't have the appropriate content encoding header in your index.php), your request doesn't take all the cache headers

Answer (score 0):

closing of IfModule may fix your problem

`<IfModule mod_expires.c>`

i modify this for you

```html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
ExpiresDefault      "access plus 1 month"
# cache.appcache needs re-requests 
# in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
# Your document html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# RSS feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz|woff)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```